# Force file and sub-directory permissions on OS X server

Tags: macos, permissions, chmod

We have an OS X development server at work for five developers, creating mainly Symfony2 based websites. Out of the five only two of us are in the sudo group, meaning if the others had issues with permissions they wouldn't be able to just sudo fix them.

I've put us all in a `developers` group, including the Apache user, and set the group of the root directory of all the websites to `developers`. I've also added the `setgid` flag, so any sub-dirs and files created within will inherit the group. This works perfect.

The only problem is that any files or sub-directories created by Symfony2 (namely the cache and log files) are not being created with the group **writeable** permission. I've come across the `chmod +a` option, and attempted to set-up an ACL entry as so:

```
sudo chmod -R +a "developers allow write" path/
```

Which added a "+" to the end of the permissions list shown with `ls`. Unfortunately though new files are still not created with group write. Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those new files will not have the `group write` set as the change you made only affects the ACL of the file. ACL and POSIX-Rights are two separate things!

In my Eyes you have two options:

- Change the umask of the web-server or
- Set the ACL to the parent folder so that it gets inherited downwards. As the ACL gets checked first any read or write-permissions set here should be used by the server.

The second alternative would be - in my opinion - the better one as it doesn't matter what umask is set in the PHP-Application creating your files or folders as it is set on the system level.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The `chmod +a -R` command I tried before was applied to the root of the web server files, but it didn't seem to work. Should I use `find` to apply it to every single file?

Comment: You have to apply it to all already existing files. Important is that it is applied to the parent folder. Have a look at http://www.ideocentric.com/technology/articles/title/osx-acl for more information on apples implementation on ACLs.

Comment: I think I know what I need to do :) I've left the office now though, but I will give it another bash Monday morning. Thanks for your help!